# Does ubuntu come with little CMS color management system

Tags: color-management

Does Ubuntu come with the little CMS libraries or do i have to install them myself. I am looking for a Linux that does.

Comment: Close voters, could you read the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu comes with Little CMS officially supported since at least Ubuntu 10.04. It's installed by default in at least 13.04 (not sure about the other versions).